# expression for ng-model from int to ASCII

Tags: angularjs

How can I convert int to ASCII (capital letters) without the use of a controller?
What should be the **expression**?

The following expression was not working out for me:

`{{ String.fromCharCode(64 + no_of_sets)}}`

where *no_of_sets* is from ng-model.
I want the output from, say 1 to be A, 2 to be B... and so on.

Comment: Expressions are not JavaScript, you can't execute arbitrary logic within them.  You can, however, call a function that is defined on `$scope` to execute the logic.  `String.fromCharCode()` isn't something defined on `$scope`.

Comment: Or you can write a filter that does that, and than call {{no_of_sets|youFilterName}}, that will not be depended on a controller, only on the filter

Comment: Thanks all, I have made a controller to the job :)